# Создание простого web приложения на Java, tomcat, db2

Tags: java

дали тестовое задание, разработать приложение, как сделать, есть знание java, посоветуйте онлайн курс где делают подобное чтобы по шагам воспроизвести хотя бы примерный функционал.

> Интерфейс на стороне клиента должен иметь поле ввода номера СНИЛС, который будет искаться в СУБД на стороне сервера. При вводе номера СНИЛС на стороне клиента должна осуществляться проверка на его корректность, путем проверки контрольной суммы.
> В случае, если контрольная сумма СНИЛС не совпала, об этом должно выводиться предупреждение оператору.
> После ввода СНИЛС производиться поиск по СУБД и пользователю выводиться результат о наличии или отсутствии данного СНИЛС в базе данных.
> Так же в пользовательском интерфейсе должна быть реализована функция загрузки текстового файла содержащего набор записей СНИЛС в формате «ХХХ-ХХХ-ХХХ ХХ», где каждый СНИЛС в отдельной строке (двухбайтовый разделитель 0x0D ОхОА).
> По результатам загрузки текстового файла должен формироваться отчет, содержащий информацию, о результат проверки СНИЛС, со следующими вариантами НАЙДЕН, ОТСУТСТВУЕТ, НЕВЕРЕН (в случае некорректности контрольной суммы).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите этот канал.
https://www.youtube.com/c/letsCodeDru

плейлист: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU2ftbIeotGoGSEUf54LQH-DgiQPF2XRO

И возможно эта статья Вам поможет: https://nakov.com/blog/2016/08/05/creating-a-blog-system-with-spring-mvc-thymeleaf-jpa-and-mysql/

В этих ресурсах показоно создание блога, соц-сетей, но по аналогии можете реализовать свою идею, в частности в построении начальной архитектуры приложения.